# Print Multiple HTML files automatically using a printer/Network Printer

Tags: html, printing, epson, network-printers, android-print-framework

I looking for a solution to print multiple HTML files/URLs to print automatically from the printer with Just one click from my custom android app.

So earlier I use to print these multiple files using Google Cloud API. So using that API we use to add those files to the Google cloud and then Google Cloud automatically prints those HTML files from the printer which is configured. Since Google cloud is no more available to use so I am looking for an automatic solution.

Is there any solution for printing multiple HTML files using EPSON printer tm-t20 by using some API OR some android code which I can integrate to print these HTML automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I suggest asking a series of more focussed questions to get specific answers to the various problems you are faced with. Anyway here are some ideas for you...

There are a few things going on here. You need to process a URL, convert that URL into something printable (probably a PDF file) and then automate the printing of it on your Epson printer.

Software is available to automatically print documents that appear in a folder on your network, so you can use that kind of thing to print PDFs. Google "automatically print pdf files in folder" and find something that will work with your printer.

For the other problem of getting something printable from a URL, I presume you do not wish to code up your own solution, so perhaps you can find an App to render HTML to PDF and save the file to a folder or network location. Have a look at IFTT, there is an app there called Pocket, that can convert a URL to PDF and save it to Google Drive.  If you link Google Drive to the folder on your network that automatically prints documents, perhaps you will have a solution!

Comment: We tried to generate pdf and tries to print the same but in that, we are getting extra space when we are printing it on the paper roll of the printer so to remove that extra space we create HTML without page break so that they can print continuously on the print roll but now the problem is with tear-off i.e. invoices are not getting tear-off automatically as it is printed from one complete HTML file.
Is there any way to fix this invoice not getting tear off automatically?

Comment: It will always be problematic converting HTML to PDF, it's a bad idea . Can you not obtain the invoice details as data e.g. JSON and then create the PDF programmatically from that on locally installed software on-site. Or obtain data for mail merge (Office APIs). You will then be in control of the formatting and page sizes and could create individual files per invoice that (I presume) will "tear-off".

Comment: I am using continuous paper roll in the printer. No specific paper size. Also I am not facing any issue with the pdf formatting. When I open in browser is seems fine but when it prints it add extra white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ezeep print api it is a replacement for gooogle ckoud print,
I'm the developer community manager  I help people with the api integrations and the pai is pretty easy to use . check it out at ezeep.com
let me know if oyu need help